# In the terminal I can't open main.cpp file using codeblocks

Tags: command-line, code-blocks

I've installed this tool [Text](https://github.com/xalanq/cf-tool/releases). It's a tool to use in Text. This tool works from inside the terminal and I need to code using Codeblocks IDE so how can i open a .cpp file in Codeblocks using the terminal?